# Network manager is sending me to a "hotspot login" page

Tags: network-manager, dns

The last few months I've had a question mark on my network connectivity icon in the top bar(gnome). I discounted this as a defect in a canonical server for some reason not being reachable by me.

Starting today, network manager starts a web browser that shows a page that is supposed to take me to a "hotspot login" page. This is on my home network that seems to be running perfectly fine.

Why is this? I can't find anything relevant in logs.

On a maybe unrelated note, I can't resolve gfycat. gfycat has been unreachable for me for approximately the same duration as the question mark.

Comment: Can I confirm the issue here? Wifi hasn't worked for *months*, and now you're being prompted to sign into a hotspot? Are you certain that your installation is connected to the home Wifi station and not another? Could the name of your Wifi station be the same as a nearby hotspot, which is confusing the OS?

Comment: Not using wifi. This is on a wired connection. The network itself works fine. The computer isn't wifi capable.

Comment: A wired connection going to a hotspot destination? Bizarre. Are you using custom DNS servers? It may be worthwhile to reset your network config to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @Matigo I'm using my ISPs DNS. I've had no further hotspot popups after a reboot.

Comment: @Matigo Nope, got again on reboot.